# Android: onKeyUp() event is fired even though the focus is on an EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-events, keyup

Following is what documentation says about `Activity.onKeyUp()`

> Called when a key was released and not handled by any of the views
>   inside of the activity. So, for example, key presses while the cursor
>   is inside a TextView will not trigger the event (unless it is a
>   navigation to another object) because TextView handles its own key
>   presses.

But, if I override `onKeyUp()` of an activity and check whether it gets fired when I type a key when the focus is in an `EditText`, I can see that `onKeyUp()` is getting fired in following scenarios (tested on an AVD).

- If a key is pressed via the hardware keyboard.
- If a numeric key is entered from virtual keyboard (event is not fired for character keys).

If I understood the documentation correctly, `onKeyUp()` shouldn't get fired in above cases.

So, is the documentation wrong, or have I misunderstood it?

Is there any other way I can catch keyboard events which are not handled by any other UI element?

Answer (score 1):

This does appear to be a bug because `onKeyDown` rightly isn't called if an `EditText` has focus. However that does mean we can add a hack to figure out if we should react to an `onKeyUp` event. Here's how I've dealt with it:

```
private val filteredEvents = HashMap<Long, KeyEvent>()

override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    filteredEvents.remove(event.downTime)?.let {
        Log.d("TAG", "Filtered event occurred. Handle it here.")
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
}

override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean =
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event.also { filteredEvents[it.downTime] = it })
```